# Javascript DataTables - filter() function not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the DataTables javscript library and I'm trying to filter a row out based on if a numerical value is greater than 60.

I'm trying to follow this example:
http://datatables.net/reference/api/filter%28%29

The filter code looks like this:

```
table
    .column( 3 )
    .data()
    .filter( function ( value, index ) {
        return value > 60 ? true : false;
    } )
```

The problem is all rows are still visible and no filtering has been done at all. Even if my function simply returns false all rows are still visible. What's going on here?

JSFiddle of example

http://jsfiddle.net/1hLcpr3x/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The example you're linking to is filtering the returning array of the data from the columns, not the rows themselves.

You can verify this by returning the content and logging it

```
var filteredArray = table.column( 3 )
                         .data()
                         .filter( function(value, index) {
                             return value > 60 ? true : false;
                         })
                         .draw();

console.log(filteredArray);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/1hLcpr3x/)

This is what the `filter` method does, it filters the data when you return it with `data()`, not the rows.

To filter the rows in place, you'd hook into the DataTables plugin, more specifically `$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering`, and do something like this

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
        return aData[3] < 60;
    }
);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/1hLcpr3x/3/)

[Documentation for DataTables filtering](https://datatables.net/development/filtering)

Comment: I have multiple datatables on a page, how do I make sure my custom hooked filter only works with the one I want? Can I derive the table from the passed in settings object?

Comment: @CanÜrek - what do you mean it's not working? It filters out anyone with an age of 60 or more, and in the last fiddle there are no rows whith persons older than 59, so it's working just fine ?

Comment: sorry to comment this late... but $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push is not working for me...I keep getting this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in console..